# How to get hortonworks data platform and cloudera distribution for hadoop latest version

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm currently working on **CDH5.13 (Cloudera Distribution Hadoop)**, and i have a couple of questions:

1- I want to get the latest version of CDH(6.3.3). When i try to download it, i have this message **(Your MyCloudera account is not currently connected with a CDH subscription which is required for CDH 6.3.3 and later.)**. Where do I go to get a subscription? And what is the cost of the subscription?

2- I tried to download older versions of CDH, but it says **( As of February 1, 2021, all downloads of CDH and Cloudera Manager require a username and password and use a modified URL. You must use the modified URL, including the username and password when downloading the repository contents described below.)**. I'm assuming i have to get a license to have this username and password. Where should I go to buy this?

3- I also tried to download Hortonworks Data Platform, but i have this message **(You must be a HDP customer to access these downloads. If you believe you should have access to these then please reach out to support or your customer service representative.)**. How to become an HDP customer? And what is the cost?

4- I managed to donwload **Hortonworks Data Platform Sandbox**, so i'm assuming it's free, but i must become a HDP customer to download **Hortonworks Data Platform**. So what's the difference between these two?

Sorry for the long message and thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now all Cloudera products are behind a paywall. You need to get a license from Sales team and with the license, you can generate paywall credentials from [here](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/cdh.html#download_text_section). Either it could be a 60 days free trial license or paid one. All your questions are answered **[here](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/paywall-expansion.html)**

Contact Sales team from [here](https://www.cloudera.com/contact-sales.html)

Comment: Those downloads still aren't the latest version, even with support subscription, last I checked.